# NFC taps counter

Tags: android, nfc

Hy!

I am working on my NFC project for my diploma thesis and I want to make 2 things:

1) When I tap NFC tag with my phone I want that browser on my phone connect me to my website.

2) I want to make that when my NFC tag is tapped count numbers of taps so I can later read that number with my android app and send it to database on my server, so I can make statistics about how many times my NFC tag has been tapped.

So far I have accomplished my first task and my phone browser propertly display my website when I tap NFC tag but now I have problem with my second task. I have searched on internet for some tutorials and I havent found any good tutorial how to programm NFC tag to count numbers of taps. I have found examples how to read and write NdefMessages on NFC Tag, but I am still confused how to make that my NFC Tag remember URL of my website and to increment integer number and remember it at the same time. So far I know, my NFC Tags are rewritable, when I try to save one value, last value that was stored on NFC Tag is erased, so maybe it is not possible that NFC Tag store website URL and increased number at the same time. I don't know how to manage that...

If anyone knows good solution or link of some good tutorial pls post it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is not standard functionality in an NFC tag. I can think of 2 possible ways forward. One is to get (buy online) a programmable contactless smart card, for example a Java Card compatible card, such as a JCOP card, or a BasicCard (perhaps a bit more obscure, but easier to buy online). Then write your own smart card applet ([NFC Forum Type 4 Tag](http://www.nfc-forum.org/specs/spec_list/) compliant) that can store an NDEF message and count how many times it has been read. The other option is to get hold of a new tag such as NTAG213 or one of its variants (see [datasheet](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/NTAG213_215_216.pdf), section 8.6), which has a read counter built in. However, this tag type is not (yet) generally available, I believe.

Comment: As a note, the NTAG210 and 212 don't have a counter. The 213, 215 and 216 do. At the moment, we don't believe it's possible however to enable the counter with an Android phone. Samples available (NFC guy) if any Android dev wants to test.

Comment: I have samples of all of them, but thanks for the offer anyway ;) The counters can actually be enabled with an Android device: simply write the proper configuration bytes to the right page address. It's a bit of a puzzle, though, to figure out what exactly you need to write to it.

Answer (score 0):

With a simple memory NFC tag you can read the current NDEFMessage, increment the counter value and store the complete NDEFMEssage back to the tag. This way you will keep the other information (URL...).